# Error at time of Wordpress Installation

Tags: database, errors

Following error accure at the time of installation. Please help

WordPress database error: [Error on delete of 'C:\xampp\tmp#sql894_b5_31.MYD' (Errcode: 13 - Permission denied)]
SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `wp_users`

Answer (score -2):

Create new database and insert correct creditals and try again, you have probably used corrupted database file first time.

Comment: Please **[edit] your answer**, and add an explanation: **why** could that solve the problem?